# Why isn't disabling magic quotes in php.ini taking effect?

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

I disabled magic quotes at the end of my *php.ini* file in my root directory and there was no change. I am still getting backslashes in front of single quotes in *$_POST* entries. So I put a *php.ini* file in the same directory as the PHP file being run and only included the lines disabling magic quotes, but there still isn’t any change.

What am I missing here?

PHP 5.3.24 on a [GoDaddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoDaddy) shared server.

The *php.ini* file:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Comment: What does http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php shows you?

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: It might be you cannot override the main php.ini (are you on a shared hosting?). Also, did you restarted the server?

Comment: It is a shared server(GoDaddy). Is restarting a shared server possible?

Comment: phpinfo() says that magic_quotes_gpc is on

Comment: check phpinfo's output for WHICH .ini file(s) it's using. You may be editing the wrong one, or there's a .ini being parsed after the one you editted, which is turning the setting back on.

Comment: @MarcB This seems to be the issue. It is loading php5.ini in a directory that I don't see in FileZilla(/web/conf/php5.ini).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** As of php 7.4 this option is deprecated and it is removed in php 8.0

---

You could try it with a [`.htaccess`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file. You will need this line:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

As GoDaddy Shared Server doesn't accept this above option try this instead:

You have to make a file named like `php5.ini` and place this in the root folder. You can add just only the three lines you need or you can copy the `php.ini` file that you have on your local computer and edit the changes you want.

Comment: I tried disabling it through `.htaccess` and got a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I don't see anything in that answer about disabling magic quotes that hasn't already been mentioned. Could you clarify which part specifically you are talking about?

Comment: Perfect, changing the name of my php.ini to php5.ini worked. Thanks

Comment: The link is broken: *"404 Not Found"*